# Got lots of '\x00' prefix when using StringRedisTemplate

Tags: spring-data-redis

I'm putting string to redis server:

```
stringRedis.opsForValue().set(redisKey, email, ACTIVATION_CODE_TIMEOUT);
```

But I finally got '\x00\x00\x00\x00 ... my-value' in redis:
[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure it was not there already?

Comment: Oh, it's my fault. The third parameter of `set()` method is not timeout value. It's offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about this asking. It's my fault. I made mistakes about using the `set()`method. The third parameter of set() method is not timeout value. It's offset. To fix it:

```
stringRedis.opsForValue().set(redisKey, email, ACTIVATION_CODE_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```